# Date format in XLS file using php

Tags: php, date, xls

I have the following function to create a xml for xls file using php.

```
private function addRow ($array)
{
    $cells = "";
    foreach ($array as $k => $v):
            $type = 'String';
            if (is_numeric($v))
            {
                    $type = 'Number';
            }else if ($v===date('Y-m-d',strtotime($v))) {
                    $type = 'Date';
            }

            $v = htmlentities($v, ENT_COMPAT, $this->sEncoding);
            $cells .= "<Cell><Data ss:Type=\"$type\">" . $v . "</Data></Cell>\n"; 
    endforeach;
    $this->lines[] = "<Row>\n" . $cells . "</Row>\n";
}
```

Here `$type = 'Date';` is not working as a date type in created xls file,it will create a correpted xls file.
When i give it as `$type = 'String';`,file will created ,but that field not detecting as a date.

Comment: Just encountered the same problem but with $type = 'General' and $type='Number', in fact, the only type accepted is 'String'. any solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XlS file with date format php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419077/xls-file-with-date-format-php)